# python flask and heroku webapp ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Tags: python, ssl, heroku, web, flask

I'm adding two other pages in my python flask and heroku (free plan) web app: http://www.getrandomnumbers.com/, but I get a ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR when I try to reach my new pages (whatever the web browser I use).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heroku's Automated Certificate Management SSL service is [only included with paid dynos](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl):

> Heroku SSL is included for free on any app that uses paid dynos: Hobby, Standard-1X, Standard-2X, Performance-M and Performance-L. This service uses Server Name Indication (SNI), an extension of the TLS protocol, which allows for Heroku to terminate SSL on its router.

Otherwise you need to manually set up SSL using your own certificate. The easiest (and likely cheapest) option is to upgrade your dyno to the $7 per month hobby tier.